# Как запустить APK?

Tags: android, apk, root

Есть код установки через Root.

```
command = "adb install -r " + file;
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "su", "-c", command });
```

Как можно после установки его запустить?.

У меня есть идея типо узнать имя из APK, а после используя PackageManager запустить это приложение.

Есть способы или идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно так

```
try {
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.package_name");
context.startActivity(intent );
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: Молодец, только давайте вы повнимательнее почитаете что мне требуется).

Так как Имя пакета неизвестно. То что вы вставите в таком случае в getLaunchIntentForPackage?

Comment: То есть после того как установилось приложение, надо сразу узнать его package name?

Comment: Да. В этом и вся проблема что я не знаю как узнать имя пакета НЕ установленного приложения.

Ну или установить и сразу его запустить

Comment: Вообще сразу бросается такое решение: после установки приложения, пробежаться циклом по всем установленным программам, и взять из последнего package name. Если память не изменяет, то вроде как с помощью PackageInfo можно такое сделать

Comment: Ок спс)........

Comment: Слушайте, а как запустить если я получил не имя пакета. А имя приложения?

тоесть не com.asd.asd
А простой asd

Comment: =) Мне кажется такое невозможно. Например изза того, что несколько приложений могут иметь одно и тоже название.

Comment: Ясно спс)).......